# what is the method to delete hashmap entry

Tags: java, hashmap

How to delete an entry in `HashMap`?
I am creating an application of "GPS based reminder"

I have used the following:

```
 Map<String, Long> timeMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

This introduces a `HashMap`. Here I have all my reminders and `HashMap` is used so that I can give a reminder after 10 minutes if the user is still in range.

If the user accepts the entry then the entry gets deleted from the database. But as the entry still exists in the `HashMap` the app gives a reminder.
Kindly give me the solution for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: the statement is:                                                                         Map<String, Long> timeMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();

Comment: `map.remove()`?

Comment: What key do you use to create an entry in your `HashMap`?

Comment: I use this :                                               timeMap.put(str, ct);

Comment: Then: `timeMap.remove(str)`.

Comment: `map.remove(Object)` or `map.remove(Object, Object)` // PS : Don't use raw types with collections.

Comment: is there any method to delete by comparing the str of the row.?

Comment: @IshaP - What do you mean by that?

Comment: means I have string and long for each entry in hashmap. Now i thought of comparing the string of each entry oof hashmap with string of the row that i want to delete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to remove the entry with:

```
Map.remove(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to use iterator.

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> _iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); _iterator.hasNext(); ) {
          Map.Entry<String, String> entry = _iterator.next();
          if(entry.getKey().equals("your value")) {
            _iterator.remove();
          }
        }
```

Comment: I have <String , Long > how to get only string and compare it? And then how would i delete that entry.

Comment: entry.getKey().equals(Object o)

Comment: Ok can you accept my answer so that it may help someone in future

Comment: Actually @karthik it worked only for once. It is not working from the next. Please tell me some other way to do it. Also check out the entries of hash MAP.

Comment: pass the object values in for loop

Comment: how to do it?? @karthik